# Where is Van Kampen's theorem about curves and two-sided surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

I am looking for this theorem:

> For any C there is always a smooth two-sided surface which doesn't cross itself, and whose boundary is C

I saw this statement [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-c-line-integrals-and-stokes-theorem/session-94-simply-connected-regions-topology/MIT18_02SC_MNotes_v14.pdf) on page 2 with a note

> This was first proved around 1930 by van Kampen

But I don't find this theorem anywhere. Where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two-sided embedded surfaces which bound a smooth curve (also called a knot) $C$ are known as [Seifert surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_surface) for the knot. I don't know a precise reference to van Kampen's result but the Wikipedia article seems to disagree he was the first to prove the existence of a Seifert surface for every knot. If you're looking for a proof, there's an algorithm for constructing them, which you can find all over the internet or in any knot theory book.

Comment: My education in topology is severely lacking. So +1 and Thanks for getting me to read that Wikipage. Cool stuff!